# How to retrieve photos from requested album in django?

Tags: django

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')

class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250,
            help_text='Maximum 250 characters.', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True,
            help_text='Suggested value automatically generated from title. Must be unique.', null=True)
    caption = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=250,
            help_text='An optional summary.')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos',
            help_text='Maximum resolution 800x600. Larger images will be resized.')

    album = models.ForeignKey(Album) 

    class Meta:
            ordering = ['-date']
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

I have something like this in models.py and i want to write a function in views which select all the photos related to the requested album and return it in the corresponding html page

```
def album_list(request):
    album_choice = Album.objects.all()

    return render(request, "talks/gallery.html", {'album_choice':album_choice})

def photo_list(request):
    queryset = Photo.objects.filter
    context = {
            "photos" : queryset,
            }
    return render(request, "talks/", context)
```

Also I have just this in views.py so suppose a user clicks on particular category and then it opens up to show the images related to it. how do I retrieve this information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')

    def get_photos(self):
        return Photo.objects.filter(album=self)

class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250,
            help_text='Maximum 250 characters.', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True,
            help_text='Suggested value automatically generated from title. Must be unique.', null=True)
    caption = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=250,
            help_text='An optional summary.')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos',
            help_text='Maximum resolution 800x600. Larger images will be resized.')

    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)

    class Meta:
            ordering = ['-date']
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

Views.py

```
def album_list(request):
#view for all albums
    album_choice = Album.objects.all()
    return render(request, "talks/gallery.html", {'album_choice':album_choice})

def photo_list(request, pk=None):
#view for particular album view
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=pk)
    queryset = Photo.objects.filter
    context = {
            "album" : album,
            }
    return render(request, "talks/", context)


#in your template for a particular album view
{% for photo in album.get_photos %}
   <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

In template for all album views, to load related photos for each album

```
{% for album in album_choice %}
    {% for photo in album.get_photos %}
        <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```